# Curl or Lynx: stripping Javascript possible?

Tags: curl, cygwin, javascript, lynx

I am doing corpus generation through curl or lynx of some web pages. I have written a program in bash to strip away the html code (e.g., when I do lynx -source myurl), but the problem is that some pages have JavaScript, which does not get stripped away.

Is there any way using curl or lynx to not get Javascript? I do want the html coding in the first instance to get my main body data, that's why I didn't use lynx -dump option (and instead used lynx -source).

I think I am asking for too much here. Or if you know about any JavaScript stripping app that can work in Cygwin environment, please let me know. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291789/remove-all-javascript-from-an-html-page and https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text.

Comment: Thanks for the links: I will see what the first one leads to. The github link does not seem useful for my case, as I have anyway stripped off the html stuff through coding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mention of source-transformation in the manual page for [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html).  So I think the answer is "no" there.

For `lynx`, you get much the same answer: it treats `<script>` tags as almost the same as comments (with some special handling for the closing tag).  It has done that since around 2000 (referring to the [changelog](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/CHANGES.html#v2.8.4dev.5)).

But `lynx` does not (yet) have an option for stripping comments (and scripts) from the download.

You might be able to use [`tidy`](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/tidy_man.html) to reformat the file to simplify scripting a do-it-yourself script-removal tool.  For example, using the `-wrap` with a large value (such as the file size) will put all of the HTML tags in the first column, allowing a simple script to parse the result and discard `<script>` through `</script>`, etc.

Comment: Thanks; I think I will have to see if I can find some kind of pattern then, which is not present otherwise in the text and does not affect the main body text of the page, so that I can write a code to remove it.